# Is there a working Cocoa MySQL Xcode project?

Tags: mysql, cocoa, xcode

Or has this been abandoned? I can't seem to find a modern sample project. I haven't been able to make any the old code I find work. I just want to write a simple Mac app that accesses an external MySQL database that's also involved in a PHP website.

Answer (score 0):

The old CocoaMySQL project has been abandoned, but the project has been resurrected as [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/).

It's open source and you can get the source code [here](http://www.sequelpro.com/docs/Source_Code).

If you want a straight library that allows you to access MySQL, you might try the commercial [MacSQL framework.](http://www.rtlabs.com/fwork/index.html)

You can also just use the MySQL C API directly, however be careful because if you want to use this in a commercial app the licensing fees are high.

You might find it easier to write some PHP code on the server to deliver the results to your client using JSON or some other lightweight data interchange format. PHP has direct support for JSON and there is a [great Cocoa framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) that makes it easy to parse and generate JSON code.

This method allows you to completely abstract the database connection from your client, so it is relatively trivial to change the database if necessary in future.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Rob, I have actually seen the links to Sequel Pro but I was confused when I got there. Part of my problem is that I am really bad at adding things to an Xcode project. Once I have a project in hand with the correct libraries and whatever all linked up, I can make use of the various methods or functions.

That's why I was asking if someone had a super simple project using MySQL that would hopefully compile for me right out of the box. I can then add all my objects and coding.

Can't seem to find anyone out there willing to hold the hand of us project-challenged. The project settings dialog box and codes that go in various boxes therein are very confusing to me.